# Selecting a task in MS Project with VBA

Tags: vba, ms-office, ms-project

what is the syntax for selecting a task in Microsoft Project through VBA? For example, I want to be able to make any task the active task given its UID.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this:

```
Application.Find Field:="UniqueID", Test:="equals", Value:=TaskUID
```

Note: Change `TaskUID` to the name of your variable containing the UID (Long):